# Scons: Build website based on RSS-Feeds

Tags: scons, build-tools

I want to program a build script which shall do the following thinks:

1. Download various RSS feeds from the Internet
2. Generate a static website based on the items found in the RSS feeds (one site per RSS item)

First I thought of using scons to do the build. But then I have the problem that I have to know the set of all RSS items to configure the build step (2). Because in scons there is a seperation between the configuration and execution phase, I have to configure (2) before (1) is executed but I have to execute (1) to know all RSS items.

One idea I had is to have to scons configuration files: one for build step (1) and one for build step (2) and to execute scons two times with each configuration file respectively.

Is there a better way to make this build in scons or is there another build tool more suitable for this project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

scons is more aimed at building programs, rather than aggregating RSS feeds. In passing it seems odd to generate a static page dependant on something as dynamic as an RSS feed.